# Conversion to CNF

Tags: java, algorithm, cnf

This is for an assignment. I have to convert the set of statements to CNF and implement them. I know that I need to convert the input in prefix notation it to infix first and then repeatedly apply De Morgans's Laws. However, I don't know how to proceed with the implementation after converting it to infix notation.

1. Do I have to convert it to infix or is there a better process to do this?
2. I have been reading up on BDDs from the implementation in Python [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Etylers/PyBool.cgi). I'm coding in Java and I'd like to do it by myself without using any external libraries. Any pointers on the implementation algorithm? Am I going in the right direction converting it to infix?

Thanks!

Comment: Regular CNF or 3-CNF?

Comment: Just CNF. Also, I need to perform first order resolution from the knowledge base(input).

Comment: What does the input look like?  Is it a big ugly string you need to parse, or does it come somewhat pre-parsed for you?

Comment: Sample input : (=> W H)
(=> C H)
(NOT H)
(OR (AND A B) (AND A C))
(<=> A D) But other samples involve more variables and many more levels of nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert this to infix - you want to get out of the domain of strings as quickly as possible, for example

```
public abstract class Expression
public abstract class BinaryExpression extends Expression {
    private Expression expr1;
    private Expression expr2;
    public Expression getExpr1() { return expr1; }
    public void setExpr1(Expression expr) { expr1 = expr; }
}
public abstract class UnaryExpression extends Expression
public class Or extends BinaryExpression
public class Not extends UnaryExpression
```

and so on.  To parse the input into `Expressions` you may find it useful to use a [Recursive Descent Parser](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html), although this is certainly not the only way to parse your input.  Once you have your input converted to a symbolic `Expression` format it should be much easier to apply the boolean laws to convert it to CNF.

Comment: Ok that's for solving the CNF so that I can use it for the FOL right? I want to display the input in CNF form. Sorry if I'm not getting you.

Comment: The output I should Get for the above input is (OR (NOT W) H)
(OR (NOT C) H)
(NOT H)
(A)
(OR B C)
(OR (NOT A) D)
(OR (NOT D) A) RDP, afaik, only solves it but doesn't let me display it in CNF.

Comment: The Expression classes are for converting the input to CNF, since it's easier to manipulate symbols than strings. For the output you would use the classes' `toString` methods, e.g. for the `Or` class the `toString` method would be `return "(OR" + getExpr1().toString() + " " + getExpr2().toString() + ")"`